# Can I place an html img tag behind an html table that contains background images?

Tags: css

As the title implies, is it possible to place an img tag behind a table that contains background images?

**[Here](http://www.hydrocell.co/layout.html)** is an example and also the page source

The table contains background images

Comment: Behind means in `td` tags? because you said background images not background image.

Comment: @venkateshwar No I mean the image must go behind the background images that are in the td tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `position: relative;` to your table and you will get the desired result

AS:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" style="position: relative;z-index:2; margin-top:-170px;">
....
</table>
```

**NOTE:** Using Inline CSS is not a good idea try [external Stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html)